# PrimeFaces : How to reference dataTable from a tree, both nested in the same tabView

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need some help to "ajaxify" a tree and a dataTable, both nested in the same tabView. I've searched the primefaces forum ([did a post about it there](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=35786)) and stackoverflow, but didn't find related problems.

Basically, I've got a p:tabView component whose tabs contain both a tree component and a dataTable component. The tree is correctly updated when I select another tab. But what I can't get to work is updating the dataTable when I select a node from the tree component.

Indeed, if I add a p:ajax tag inside the p:tree :

```
<p:ajax event="select"
update=":form:myTabView:#{myBean.currentTabIndex}:myDataTable"
listener="#{myController.doSelectNode}" />
```

in order to trigger this update, the page doesn't load anymore, giving me the exception :

*Cannot find component with expression ":form:myTabView:0:myDataTable" referenced from "form:myTabView:0:tree".*

It seems weird as I can see from the generated html that it generates a `<table id="form:myTabView:0:myDataTable">`

I've tried all other possible values for the update attribute ("myTabView:0:myDataTable", "myDataTable" ...), but to no avail.

Environment : PrimeFaces 4.0 / JSF 2.1.2 / Tomcat 7.0.47

Here is the code. Note that it works well outside of a tabView, with a p:ajax update value of ":form:myDataTable".

**The simplified xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Bienvenue</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:tabView id="myTabView" value="#{myBean.tabs}" var="currentTab"
            dynamic="true" cache="true" activeIndex="#{myBean.currentTabIndex}">

            <p:tab id="tab" title="#{currentTab.title}">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <p:tree id="tree" value="#{myBean.treeList[myBean.currentTabIndex]}" var="node"
                            selectionMode="single" selection="#{myBean.selectedNode}"
                            cache="true">

                            <p:ajax event="select"
                                update=":form:myTabView:#{myBean.currentTabIndex}:myDataTable"
                                listener="#{myController.doSelectNode}" />

                            <p:treeNode>
                                <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                            </p:treeNode>
                        </p:tree>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:dataTable id="myDataTable" value="#{myBean.selectedUIModelList}"
                            var="uIModel">
                            <h:column>
                                <p:panel header="" closable="true">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{uIModel.name}" />
                                </p:panel>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>

        </p:tabView>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**MyBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {
    private List<MyTab> tabs;
    private int currentTabIndex;
    private TreeNode selectedNode;
    private List<TreeNode> treeList;
    private List<UIModel> selectedUIModelList;

    public MyBean() {
        currentTabIndex = 0;

        // build tabs list
        tabs = new ArrayList<>();
        MyTab tab = new MyTab();
        tab.setTitle("Tab1");
        tabs.add(tab);
        tab = new MyTab();
        tab.setTitle("Tab2");
        tabs.add(tab);

        treeList = new ArrayList<>();

        // build trees
        // tree for Tab1
        TreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        TreeNode parentNode1_1 = new DefaultTreeNode("tab1_node1", root);
        TreeNode childNode1_1_1 = new DefaultTreeNode("tab1_node1_1", parentNode1_1);
        TreeNode childNode1_1_2 = new DefaultTreeNode("tab1_node1_2", parentNode1_1);
        TreeNode parentNode1_2 = new DefaultTreeNode("tab1_node2", root);
        TreeNode childNode1_2_1 = new DefaultTreeNode("tab1_node2_1", parentNode1_2);
        treeList.add(root);

        // tree for Tab2        
        TreeNode root2 = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        TreeNode parentNode2_1 = new DefaultTreeNode("tab2_node1", root2);
        TreeNode childNode2_1_1 = new DefaultTreeNode("tab2_node1_1", parentNode2_1);
        TreeNode childNode2_1_2 = new DefaultTreeNode("tab2_node1_2", parentNode2_1);
        TreeNode parentNode2_2 = new DefaultTreeNode("tab2_node2", root2);
        TreeNode childNode2_2_1 = new DefaultTreeNode("tab2_node2_1", parentNode2_2);
        treeList.add(root2);        

        //instantiate UIModel list
        selectedUIModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

        ... Getters and setters ...

}
```

**MyTab.java**

```
public class MyTab {
    private String title;

        ... Getters and setters ...
}
```

**UIModel.java**

```
public class UIModel {
    private String name;

        ... Getters and setters ...
}
```

**MyController.java**

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyController {
    @ManagedProperty("myBean")
    private MyBean myBean;

    public void doSelectNode(NodeSelectEvent event) {
        String selectedStringNode = ((String)event.getTreeNode().getData());
        UIModel newUIModel = new UIModel();
        newUIModel.setName(selectedStringNode);
        myBean.getSelectedUIModelList().add(newUIModel);
    }

        ... Getters and setters ... 
}
```

Can you suggest where I've made a mistake, or point me to a related resource ?

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: already tried without implicit index? `:form:myTabView:myDataTable`. i learnt you have to indicate the hierarchy in the coded view not that in the generated one

Comment: thanks Michele ! you saved my day(s)... not very intuitive, but should have thought about it. Maybe you can add your comment as an answer so that I tag this question as solved ?

Answer (score 1):

already tried without implicit index? `:form:myTabView:myDataTable`. i learnt you have to indicate the hierarchy in the coded view not that in the generated one